# Strange error when map is removed from view in app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

Error:  I get this error each time I view a map on my app:

> 2019-12-27 08:24:48.777792-0500 [6608:1641158] [VKDefault] TextureAtlasPage: Atlas page destroyed with outstanding references.: Assertion with expression - _textureRefs == 0 : Failed in file - /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1606.32.10.8.3/src/TextureAtlas.cpp line - 604

Does anyone know what this means? I've searched Google and can't find an answer?

Platform: Xcode 11.3

Comment: Can you share the code where you are implementing the map?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like a bug with xcode 10 or swift 4.

Comment: I also got this problem, for me the cause is, I only dragged a mapView to myViewController, but did not use location manager to set the region of the mapView.

Comment: I think you can trap the warning by implementing `static func dismantleUIView` in the *MapView* view struct.  Other than finding this question, I haven't investigated further yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same warning too. Obviously it is an internal MKMapView issue.

Moreover, this happens only if map type is set to "Standard". So, to avoid this warning I am changing map type to "Satellite" just before closing the map view:

```
[self.mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeSatellite];
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve gotten such a decision.

```
deinit {

            mapView.annotations.forEach{mapView.removeAnnotation($0)}

            mapView.delegate = nil

            print("deinit: MapViewController")
      }
```